# How can I implement a composite channel (RGB) curve filter like the one in photoshop in IOS?

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, filter, photoshop

I have looked at the esilverberg's implementation https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters and brad Larson's GPU based implmentation https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage . In both the implementation they have implemented separate red,green,blue channel curve filters. However, in photoshop there is one composite RGB channel curve filter also apart from the separate R,G,B channel filters. How can I implement this filter?

Comment: Isn't Photoshop's composite tone curve adjustment just a ganging of curves across red, green, and blue channels? That is, don't they apply the same curve to all three? That's how I handle a curve when using `-setRGBControlPoints:`, and I haven't had someone complain about that since this got added.

Comment: I've same issue with https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage it's really cool library but I cannot apply composite channel curve with that too.

Comment: The effects are not the same brad you can check...thanks for the awesome work btw man!

Comment: Anyone get the correct way to apply curve on image? GPUImage is not working with all curve files. Strange behavior.